# Passing variable into head.phtml

Tags: variables

I want to generate dynamic meta title categories, based on category level.

In view.phtml category this is my code:

```
<?php
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getTopCategory();
    $level = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getLevel();
    $curCatName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
    $halaman = "Halaman ".Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();
    $suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
    $newMetaTitle = "";
    if($level == 1){
        $newMetaTitle = "Sell"." "."any"." ".$curCatName." ".$suffix;
    }
    if($level == 2){
        $newMetaTitle = "Sell"." ".$curCatName." "."more items"." | ".$halaman." | ".$this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName()." ".$suffix;
    }
    if($level == 3){
        $newMetaTitle = "Sell"." ".$curCatName." "."more items"." | ".$halaman." | ".$this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName()." ".$suffix;
    }

    echo $newMetaTitle;
    ?>
```

The question is: I want to pass $newMetaTitle into head.ptml. How to do that?